# Hanging a new ceiling fan - space around junction box

Tags: ceiling-fan, mounting

Need help determining if I'm following the right steps, or if I need to get an electrician to install a new junction box.

I had an old Hunter fan/light combo.  I am trying to replace with a House of Hampton fan/light.

First issue: junction box has two long screws coming down from the ceiling that the original fans mounting bracket was connected to. The new mounting bracket was, of course, too wide.  I purchased a cross bar and connected that.

Second issue: The crossbar aligns to the holes on the new mounting bracket, but the screws for the mounting bracket don't screw into the ceiling.  I'm concerned the fan will fall from the mounting bracket, not from the cross bar.  See pictures attached.  The pictures show the crossbar and the mounting bracket attached to the crossbar (note, I may have attached the crossbar incorrectly, based on other research I've done). You can also see the space in between the sides of the junction box and the drywall. The edge of the drywall is very crumbly and the width of holes in the mounting bracket actually falls in the spaces.

Any help on what I should do is appreciated.  I would prefer not to hire someone. :)

[[image: image1][image: image2][image: image3]

[image: crossbar(yes, I know I put the crossbar on wrong :))]
[image: mounting bracket]

Comment: Are you sure the new bracket won't fit over the screws coming down from the box?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  I tried to put the screws from the junction box into the bracket, but they are too narrow for the bracket.  I'm adding 2 more pictures.  I took the mounting bracket off so you can see the screws as well as the top of the mounting bracket.

Comment: @JACK - Any thoughts based on my additional pictures?  Thanks!

Comment: That round plate isn't designed for a fan mount.  I'd remove it, pull the wires down and see if there's a stamp on the box stating it's rated for a ceiling fan. That fan bracket should fit on the right box. Your configuration is very creative but I wouldn't want to be under it with a fan mounted and spinning.